# What is a possible solution

Tags: chronoforms

I'm a little joomla beginer, but I'm doing my best to teach it.
I have a question about chrono form.
Is it possible to display chrono form's resulut in some article (not like boxes for filling but data that was filled from the past to now.)

example:

I have a text box, made by ChronoForm on the site. I insert "John" and click submit button.
I want to have this name displayed under the box fields for inserting names.
**--------------**
**INSERT NAME:** [text box, made by chronoform]

**SUBMIT**       [submit button]

**INSERTED NAMES** [table]
      
      John
**--------------**

And then the other guy insert in the textbox name "Ann" and click submit button. And then he insert name "Andreas" and click submit. I want to have a table on the side (like article) which is automatically filling by these text box. As a resuluts, i want to have a table like this

**--------------**
**INSERT NAME:** [text box, made by chronoform]

**SUBMIT**       [submit button]

**INSERTED NAMES** [table]
      
      John
      
      Ann
      
      Andreas
**--------------**

And if i want to add some other name, i insert "Finn" in the text box and click submit button. Then i want to have a table like

**--------------**
**INSERT NAME:** [text box, made by chronoform]

**SUBMIT**       [submit button]

**INSERTED NAMES** [table]
      
      John
      
      Ann
      
      Andreas
      
      Finn

Sorry for my bad english, but i hope i was clearly enough with explanation of my problem.
I use ChronoForm 4

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to display ChronoForm results in an article.

Set up the first ChronoForm to save to a database table.

Set up a second ChronoForm to display the results from the database table using the "DB Multi Record Loader" action in the "On Load" section or similar.

You can include the second ChronoForm in an article using the ChronoForms plugin.

Bob Janes has created some online videos that can help:

e.g. ChronoForms v4: Database Save: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRL__AsJw9g